# Unity How to GetCompoent<Outline>() & GetCompoent<Shadow>() with a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
 public class ABCD : MonoBehaviour
        {
            [SerializeField]
            Outline outline;
            [SerializeField]
            Shadow shadow;

            private void Start()
            {
                outline = GetComponent<Outline>();
                shadow = GetComponent<Shadow>();
            }
        }
```

[image]

we knew `Outline` is Implementation `Shadow` like this.

[image]

So When I call

```
shadow = GetCompoent<Shadow>();
```

It Possible find out the Outline Compoent , because `Ouline` is also a `Shadow`.

### My question is How can I get the right Compoent?

And I can't drop the compoent to keep reference. 
Because My code exactly like this

```
//this not a monobehavior
class MyText
{
    Shadow shadow;
    Outline outline;
    public MyText(Transfrom transfrom)
    {
        outline = transfrom.GetComponent<Outline>();
        shadow = transfrom.GetComponent<Shadow>();
    }
}
```

If I create Compoent to keep reference, it will use more cost.

---

Use GetCompoents Can slove that , Anyone have better solution?

```
 foreach (Shadow s in GetComponents<Shadow>())
            {
                if (s is Outline)
                {
                    outline = s as Outline;
                }
                else
                {
                    shadow = s;
                }
            }
```

Comment: what exactly is "Text" in your example code..  if this script is being run on the above gameobject, chances are, drop the text. and it should find it

Comment: @BugFinder This "Text" is "UnityEngine.UI.Text" , And drop to text is a solution , but I don't want to make a monobehavior to keep compoent reference , it use more cost.

Comment: you arent making a monobehavior to keep the reference that code has to be somewhere, you need to run it on the gameobject, text is a component already

Comment: @BugFinder Sorry I did not explain enough , I Edited my question to explain why I can't drop the compoent.

Comment: `but I don't want to make a monobehavior to keep compoent reference , it use more cost` who told you that? .. -it is more expensive getting it on runtime via `GetComponent` than simply referencing it already via the Inspector actually ...

Comment: @derHugo because I use `object.Instantiate` , if GameObejct add more compoent  , it use more cost to clone a Gameobject.

Answer (score 1):

The `GetComponent` will always return the first available member of asked type.

You need to use Get Components to get more than one. Here's an example from https://unitygem.wordpress.com/getcomponent-in-c/

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Health : MonoBehaviour
{
     private Force [] scripts = null;
     [SerializeField] private int health = 5;

     private void Start()
     {
         this.scripts = this.gameObject.GetComponents<Force>();
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < this.scripts.Length; i++)
             {
                 if(this.scripts[i].ReportForce())
                 {
                     this.health += 5;
                 }
             }                              
         }
     }
}
```